# Issue in reading input values from TitleWindow

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe

I am facing an issue in retrieving value in ActionScript from TitleWindow mxml. Following is the UpdateRelease.mxml

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            title="Title Window" x="168" y="86">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.paul.data.ReleaseVO;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.Text;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        [Bindable]
        public var i_ReleaseVO:ReleaseVO = null;

        // Event handler for the OK button.
        protected function updateReleaseData(): void {
            if(releaseName.text == '')
                Alert.show("Release Name cannot be null");
            else if(releaseDate.text == '')
                Alert.show('Release Date cannot be null');
            else
                (parentApplication as Main).mainScreen.updateReleaseEvent();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Canvas>
    <mx:VBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Release Name"/>
        <mx:TextInput id="releaseName" width="100%" text="{i_ReleaseVO.release}"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Release Date"/>
        <mx:DateField id="releaseDate" width="100%" selectedDate="{DateField.stringToDate(i_ReleaseVO.relDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')}"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Other Info"/>
        <mx:TextInput id="relOtherInfo" width="100%" text="{i_ReleaseVO.otherInfo}"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Button label="OK" click="updateReleaseData();"/>
        <mx:Button label="Cancel" click="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Following is ActionScript code snippet

```
    public function updateReleaseEventHandler( pEvent:Event ): void {

        if(i_RequestServiceProxy != null) {
            var i_RequestParams:Object ={};
            i_HttpXMLRequest = new HttpXMLRequest();
            var obj:Object = new Object();
            obj["release"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.releaseName.text;
            obj["releaseDate"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.releaseDate.text;
            obj["otherInfo"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.relOtherInfo.text;
            i_RequestParams = i_HttpXMLRequest.getUpdateReleaseParams( obj );
            i_RequestServiceProxy.updateRelease( i_RequestParams );
        } else {
            Alert.show("i_RequestServiceProxy is NULL");
        }
    }
```

Following is MainView.mxml showing the inclusion of UpdateRelease.mxml

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mx:ViewStack id="vs">
        <views:UpdateRelease id="updateReleaseValueView" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:VGroup>
```

The issue is in the following statement in ActionScript file.
I found that the following statements don't work as expected. The execution fails at the first one below. Can someone point out what is the mistake here?

```
            obj["release"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.releaseName.text;
            obj["releaseDate"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.releaseDate.text;
            obj["otherInfo"] = this.mainView.updateReleaseValueView.relOtherInfo.text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the problem yet. But I found a different way to get around this. I declared some variables in the parent mxml (from where I launch the popup) and set those variables with values from pop-up when "OK" button click is handled. It works now. I don't think this is a good idea, but I am going to ahead with this approach until I figure out the problem with the above code.

And, I thank those who spent their time reading the question to find the problem :)